# How to set javascript timer back to ZERO upon page reload

Tags: javascript

I am using this timer with a page loader.  The problem is if a page finishes loading before the timer is up, then the next time you load the page, the timer starts where it left off the last time the page executed.  I need to make sure the count variable is set to zero on page re-load.  Thanks in advance

```
<script>
    var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1);
    var count = 0;
    function myTimer() {
        if(count < 100) {
        $('.progress').css('width', count + "%");
        count += 0.025;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.round(count) +"%";
        // code to do when loading
    } else if(count > 100) {
        // code to do after loading
        count = 0;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If you reload the page your current code will NOT continue the work. It will be executed again and the timer will start counting again from 0. Please describe what you mean by "reload the page"?

Comment: For example, i read a table and send results to another .php page but the count value only made it to 80, which is fine, it's just a calculated guess.  Then I call the page again, but to read a different table and the count value starts at 80 instead of 0.  I hope that makes sence

Comment: Ok, I understand. Please check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your code into a function which will reset the counter and start it again:

```
<script>
    var myVar;
    var count;
    function restartTimer() {
        count = 0;
        clearInterval(myVar);
        myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1);
    }
    function myTimer() {
        if(count < 100) {
            $('.progress').css('width', count + "%");
            count += 0.025;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.round(count) +"%";
            // code to do when loading
        } else if(count > 100) {
            // code to do after loading
            count = 0;
        }
    }
</script>
```

And now you just need to call `restartTimer` function wherever you want:

```
resetTimer();
```

In your case, you need to call it before every call to PHP page.